# Delete cell rows based on a value in a certain column

Tags: vba, excel-2010

I am working in Excel 10. I have a worksheet with several columns of data (from A-D). I'd like a macro that deletes all rows in which the value of any cell in Column A is zero (0).I have zeros in other columns but don't want the macro to test those, i.e. I only want the macro to test for zeros in Column A.

I have attempted multiple versions of code I've located online but they are deleting the wrong rows.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: what about using the Excel built-in 'filter' tool instead of a VBA macro?

Answer (score 0):

This will get you started:

```
Sub RowKiller()
    Dim N As Long, i As Long

    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = N To 1 Step -1
        If Cells(i, "A").Value = 0 Then Cells(i, "A").EntireRow.Delete
    Next i
End Sub
```